# How can I use google app engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, web-applications, webstore

I've begun planning a kind of web store interface that I want to work on soon. I'm starting to import products from China and want to have a completely unique feel for my site. Now I'm kinda a google fanboy and have heard alot about google app engine. Mostly I like the hosting available with google more then anything though. But I wanted to know, would the App Engine be good for what I'm making?

Namely a web store with an app like feel. I've decided, to help if I ever need to move my host, to work in web2py hosted in the App Engine. Or would I be better with django or something on a normal host?

Is google best for webapps? Or is it pretty well suited for webstores as well?

Thanks

Comment: The answer is in that  [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19962066/what-is-the-relationship-differences-between-google-app-engine-and-normal-web/20063018?iemail=1&noredirect=1#20063018).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build almost anything on GAE. As Monk would say that is a blessing and a curse. GAE is relatively new and so e commerce ventures are relatively rare. This means you would be responsible for every piece of the site. Other dedicated e commerce technologies trade some of the control and look and feel for ease of use/setup.

So in short yes you could use GAE to create an e commerce site, but you would be spending a lot of time getting it up and running and then managing it. Time you may find better spent on sales and marketing.

Comment: Well that's why I wanted to work in web2py, another framework that can work stand alone or in GAE. What do you think of that?

Comment: I think Steve's primary point was that you may want to consider more ready-made solutions for e-commerce so that you don't have to deal with the non-trivial challenge of creating such a solution from scratch (whether you choose GAE or not).

Comment: @David Thank you that was exactly my point. E-commerce is neither trivial nor without large financial risk. One way of minimizing that risk is to use an existing e-commerce package that is mature and tested on thousands of other sites and with millions of transactions.

Comment: In addition how much money could you be making using an existing solution which should be much faster to get into production, compared to the months needed to write your own.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to say if App Engine is suited to your particular needs without more details about what functionality you want your web store to present.  It also depends a little bit on your background and experience.

However, the "app like feel" and crafting a "completely unique feel" for your site is something you can accomplish on any reasonable platform - I expect the presentation style will be relatively independent of the backend you choose.