# What is the relationship/differences between Google App Engine, and "normal" web apps?

Tags: google-app-engine, web-applications, firefox-os

I was trying to start to learn about programming on Firefox OS, and I heard that it is programmed with JavaScript and HTML5, and it uses the same structures of web apps.
Said that, I'm doing a course on Udacity ( I'm a beginner) that is about web development, and it talked about how to use the Google App Engine(we just made our own websites online, using python and some structures of the GAE), and I tryied to make some relationship with what I was seeing in the Firefox website, and I just coundn't figure out nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for Firefox OS, you build application, as you wrote, with HTML5, CSS3, and JavaScript: only web technology. Those are web applications that you build to run on Firefox OS devices, and even in the browser, depending on the API you used. The application you build https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps, can be either hosted on your own server, or if you packaged it, on the Firefox OS marketplace https://marketplace.firefox.com/.

Answer (score 2):

Google App Engine is a "platform as a service model" of webapps.  What you don't need is the key.  You don't need :

- a Database Administrator
- Network technician
- a Backup Admin (you still need to make backups of your app and data but not your network config files ect...)
- the hardware at your company
- the ISP service level agreements
- there is more that Google specifically puts in over other platform as a service businesses.

Google takes care of this for you.  You just write the webapp (and back it up for a rainy day)

Answer (score 1):

I would also like to add that Google App Engine is a PaaS at the end of the day. So while technically, one can say that any web application should run, that is not always the case.

If you are using a PaaS, whether it is a Google App Engine or any others like Heroku, CloudFoundry, etc - you must understand the various Services and APIs that it provides in the different platforms that it supports. For e.g. using Google App Engine, you can choose either Java, Python or PHP to write and host your web applications. However, you have to use some of its services like Datastore, etc.

Moving any web application that you have written to a PaaS is not always straightforward. Except for the most simplistic apps that print a "Hello World", there are chances that you atleast have to do the following things:

- Migrate parts of your application to utilize the Platform Services/APIs
- Rearchitect parts of your application to take maximum advantage of the Cloud i.e. multi-tenancy, Scaling, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You could treat Google App Engine(GAE) as web server hosting with specific web framework (python or java), which can host any normal webapps.

Firefox OS webapps are written with normal web skills. So you can use GAE to 'host' Firefox webapps.
(GAE is also mentioned as one of hosting place in Mozilla Developer Network
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Trash/Publishing_the_app )

The evil detail is Firefox webapp need an extra 'manifest.webapp' file that need extra MIME host settings

`self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-web-app-manifest+json'`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Developing/Manifest#Serving_manifests

Then you are ready to host Firefox Webapp on GAE :)